# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: magento2, product, admin, magento2.3.5-p1

Running Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1, vanilla install running Luma theme.  I'm populating the site with all of my SKUs, and occasionally, after I update a product with a new image (Save & Close), it will bring me back to the product listing page and I get the spinning circle. Inspector shows this:

[image: Inspector]

If I reload the page, everything seems fine, but I think this might be the cause of 504 errors I am getting every few days. The site will not load, and my web host has to kill off all sleeping DB queries that have stacked up. Any thoughts as to how to fix this?